# Where can I find Colombia municipality geometries?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for shape files (or some similar format) of Colombia's municipality boundaries.

[Wikipedia has a map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mapa_de_Colombia_(municipios).svg) that seems to be correct and which matches another dataset that I will eventually be merging in based on municipality names and DANE codes. I've tried contacting the file creator about the underlying source data, but without success.

I've tried **GADM**, but some of the municipalities are missing/incorrect, e.g. all the way in the South Amazons should have 11 municipalities, not 8.

[image]

Here's **OpenStreeMap** with data export via [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/). Many municipalities are simply just missing, although the borders for those that are there appear to be correct and more detailed than GADM.

[image]

I guess I could try to combine departments that OpenStreeMap had all municipalities for with the GADM data, but it looks like that would still only partially get me there. And in general it just makes me a bit suspicious about using the GADM data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the WFS or WMS servers of the Instituto Geográfico Agustín Codazzi (here:http://www.igac.gov.co/wps/portal/igac/raiz/iniciohome/MapasdeColombia/Descargas). These services have different layers for geodesic features and demographics. I hope it can help you.

Iván

PD: If that doesn't work, you can check this link with the shape file I use for Colombian municipalities: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i0ao837gj5wpkic/AAAnzZf-tJIKUmZvTKrvXPMpa?dl=0

Comment: I downloaded the shape files from dropbox, thank you! I will try the WFS/WMS servers once I get QGIS working again :)

Comment: Also, I posted the same [question on GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167247/where-can-i-find-colombia-municipality-geometries), do you want to answer it there as well? If not I'll link your answer from here.

Comment: Great! Glad it can help you.